# How to translate text in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, translation, programming-languages, translate

I have a text in my API using tkinter library(i don't know if it is important). I need a script or something like thing that exists in games. For example i have english version of counter strike and i can run installer which translates game into polish version. Below images. I don't want to translate entire text manually to make separate, but polish API.

I want to turn this:

```
if messagebox.askokcancel("Warning","Are you sure you want to clear workspace? \
                           You will lose all files selected"):
```

Into this:

```
if messagebox.askokcancel("Ostrzeżenie","Jesteś pewien, że chcesz wyczyścić przestrzeń \
                           roboczą? Utracisz wszystkie wybrane pliki"):
```

English version:

[image]

Polish version (this is what i want to get by script) done manually to show the problem:

[image]

Some code as a image(no need to put more):

[image]

Comment: you could use dictionaries for languages. don't add text in messagebox, just add dictionary key and when you want to change language, just change dictionary.

Comment: Put the string in variables and and read the strings from text files. That way you will only have to translate the files.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html

Comment: Please don't post images of code-  it makes it impossible to search, forces us to transcribe the code to test/run anything, and generally causes everyone more trouble.